# How to make the parameters keep their value changed after the function is used?

Tags: java, function

I'm learning Java and I cant figure this out. I have a simple change function that changes the value of 2 parameters between them. If x = 5 and y = 7, after execution x= 7 and y =5. Is there a way in Java to keep those values changed like in c++ where you use &x, &y?

```
public static void change(int x, int y){
    x=x+y;
    y=x-y;
    x=x-y;
}
```

Comment: You can't, you have to *return* the changed values or pass in reference types with mutable contents, not primitives.

Answer (score 0):

In Java int is a primitive type. So for any primitive type you can't do it. There is a boxed primitive for every primitive in Java, but here Integer is immutable (once initialized can't change it's state) so even using Integer won't work.

So you have two solutions:

1) Use MutableInt from [apache commons jar](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableInt.html).

2) Create a wrapper class for it as below and use that.

```
public class MutableInt {

private int myInt; //default initialized with 0

public int getMyInt(){
 return myInt;
}

public void setMyInt(int myInt) {
 this.myInt = myInt;
}

}
```

And inside the `change` method

```
public static void change(MutableInt x, MutableInt y){
    x.setMyInt(x.getMyInt() + y.getMyInt());
    y.setMyInt(x.getMyInt() - y.getMyInt());
    x.setMyInt(x.getMyInt() - y.getMyInt());
}
```

Then when you get the value from **x or y** using `x.getMyInt() or y.getMyInt()`, you will get updated value.